# How do I link via Drush to a Drupal site hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, terminal, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have my folder on my terminal, and when I install a module or theme it doesnt appear on my Drupal 'appereance' or in my modules. I want to be connected via terminal/drush.

Comment: Sooo, are you looking for help connecting to AWS, or where to place your themes / modules? Title suggest one, question itself the other. Please clarify, and while at it, tell us which version of Drupal you are running ;)

Comment: Im trying to be able to use drush (for installing modules/themes). When I installed them manually into my code, they dont appear on my drupal site 'appereance' or on my modules. So my theory is that the local code is not connected to my drupal site. Im using drupal 8.

Comment: There might be exceptions, but typically you'll have Drush installed on the system where the Drupal installation resides. Then, you connect via SSH to a command line interface (e.g. Bash), and execute Drush commands in the Drupal directory. Drush itself will not get you connected to the Drupal install on a remote server - at least in no way I'm familiar with. This said, what is your process for connecting to AWS in the first place?

Comment: I used ElasticBean to deploy my Drupal site. Im trying to connect via SSH from my ec2 instance. My problem is that the changes I do on my code editor, doesnt reflect on my Drupal site.

Comment: Sadly, I am not familiar with ElasticBean, and perhaps this is why I'm not understanding your setup and where it might be causing you problems. Hopefully someone else can jump in and use the extra info you provided to help you out.